# Swift: AVPlayer - How to get length of mp3 file from URL?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm process to build my first IOS app in swift and i get stuck in the question: How to get length (duration) of a music file when streaming ?

I did research a lot and also write some line of codes for solve this problem but seem my code is not good enough.

```
 func prepareAudio() {
    audioLength = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.asset.duration) 
    playerProgressSlider.maximumValue = CFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentItem.duration))
    playerProgressSlider.minimumValue = 0.0
    playerProgressSlider.value = 0.0
    showTotalSurahLength()
} // i prepare for get the duration and apply to UISlider here

func showTotalSurahLength(){
    calculateSurahLength()
    totalLengthOfAudioLabel.text = totalLengthOfAudio
} // get the right total length of audio file


func calculateSurahLength(){
    var hour_ = abs(Int(audioLength/3600))
    var minute_ = abs(Int((audioLength/60) % 60))
    var second_ = abs(Int(audioLength % 60))

    var hour = hour_ > 9 ? "\(hour_)" : "0\(hour_)"
    var minute = minute_ > 9 ? "\(minute_)" : "0\(minute_)"
    var second = second_ > 9 ? "\(second_)" : "0\(second_)"
    totalLengthOfAudio = "\(hour):\(minute):\(second)"
} // I calculate the time and cover it
```

Anyone here who ever stuck with this problem, could you give me some suggests for fix it ? I'm very new in Swift and still learn to improve my skill.

Thanks,

Answer (score 29):

For swift:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathString), options: nil)
let audioDuration = asset.duration
let audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration)
```

Comment: Hi, If there is slow internet connection it is stopping the whole app there, and if there is not internet connection it is returning 0.0. So is there any way to do it in block? and is there any notification fired by it when the resource is available?

Answer (score 11):

The following function works with Swift 3.0 and will return a Double value containing the duration of the target file.

```
func duration(for resource: String) -> Double {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: resource))
    return Double(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))
}
```

This will take the `resource` parameter, consisting of a `String` for the filepath of the audio file, and then convert the value from a `Float64` to a `Double`.

Answer (score 6):

I have made this stuf in iOS and working perfectly.

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioUrl options:nil];
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways of solving this. This was mine.

```
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    let duration = Double(item.asset.duration.value) / Double(item.asset.duration.timescale)
```

This will return your asset's duration in seconds