# Download length from track makes app to freeze SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avaudioplayer

I've been searching for a method how to display track length from URL that is stored on the server. I found this method in [Swift: AVPlayer - How to get length of mp3 file from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155003/swift-avplayer-how-to-get-length-of-mp3-file-from-url) working fine:

```
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
let duration = Double(item.asset.duration.value) / Double(item.asset.duration.timescale)
```

Here's the problem: this peace of code completely freezes the app when I navigate to views where it shows. How can I fix this problem?

Adding the function:

```
func getDuration(url: URL) -> Double {
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    let duration = Double(item.asset.duration.value) / Double(item.asset.duration.timescale)
    return duration
}
```

Text itself:

```
                        Text(String(audioManager.getDuration(url: URL(string: "http://gameleprilucky.ru/soungs/" + (data.linkSoung ?? "abob"))!)))
                            .font(.custom("Manrope-Medium", size: 12))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines certainly shouldn't be called on UI thread and it is certain to cause unresponsive interface.

You should to the following:

- add `@State` variable called e.g. `duration`
- bind the `Text` to that variable
- calculate the duration on non-UI thread with dispatching (where to call this code is unclear from your code, but you would probably use `onAppear`)
- assign calculated value to `duration` on UI thread (again by using main dispatcher)